# Unexpected token error:awk

Tags: shell, awk

Hi i have used this code snippet to 
input a file and count the number of tabs in each line and print the result to output file, but i m getting the error

awk: cmd. line:1: Unexpected token

What could be the mistake

```
#!/bin/sh
#
FILE='unit-1-slide.txt'
OUTPUTFILE='output-for'-$FILE
COUNT=$(awk '{print gsub(/\t/,"")}'$FILE)
OUTPUT_PATH='/home/user/Desktop'
echo $COUNT > $OUTPUTFILE
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: By convention all-upper-case variable names are reserved for exported variables. Also, always quote your variables (e.g. `"$FILE"` instead of `$FILE`) to avoid undesirable consequences of filename expansion, etc. Finally, the awk command could be written more clearly as `awk -F'\t' '{print NF}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space missing before `$FILE` in

```
COUNT=$(awk '{print gsub(/\t/,"")}'$FILE)
```

so the file name is treated as part of the awk script. When the shell performs **quote removal** the quotes are removed, not replaced with spaces.